# How to handle filter for multiple functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have the following scenario where most of my functions require to return different things based on a condition.

```
def get_root_path(is_cond_met=False):
    if is_cond_met:
        return "something"
    else
        return "something else"

def get_filename(is_cond_met=False):
    if is_cond_met:
        return "file name A"
    else
        return "file name B"
```

`is_cond_met` is going to be common for all the functions I am calling. I have just put two here however I have more than 15.

**Note: Actual function contains complicated logic rather than just returning few hardcoded strings.**

```
def get_root_path(is_cond_met=False):
    if is_cond_met:
        ## 
        ## Logic 
        ## 
        return "something"
    else
        #
        # Logic 
        #
        return "something else"
```

The above code works, however doesn't seem optimal, or pythonic. Is there a better solution for this?

Comment: Can you use: `return "something" if is_conf_met else "something else"`?

Comment: If it's all just static values to begin with: `config = {'some_cond': {'root_path': 'something', 'filename': 'something'}, 'otherwise': {'root_path': ...}}`…?! You may even want to be looking at environment variables or other configuration options.

Comment: What are you trying to avoid/optimize?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function that returns such functions:

```
def conditional(a, b, default=False):
    def cond(value=default):
        return a if value else b
    return cond

get_root_path = conditional("something", "something else")
get_filename = conditional("file name A", "file name B")
```

Comment: approach is really good, however,  My functions are big with few lines or logic and at the end they return some values.

Answer (score 0):

You could effectively chain the filter functions together using a couple of generic functions like this:

```
from functools import partial


def check(condition, values):
    return values[int(condition)]

def chain(condition, values):
    return list(map(partial(check, condition), values))


root_paths = "something", "something else"
filenames = "file name A", "file name B"

values = [root_paths, filenames]

is_cond_met = False
result = chain(is_cond_met, values)
print(result)  # -> ['something', 'file name A']

is_cond_met = True
result = chain(is_cond_met, values)
print(result)  # -> ['something else', 'file name B']
```